# Merge different kinds of android gradients programmatically

Tags: android, gradient, android-custom-view

I have a question about android gradients (RadialGradient and LinearGradient).

As you can see on the image above, I made two tests :

- **First circle** : LinearGradient from blue to red

```
    private fun createLinearGradient(centerRingX: Float, centerRingY: Float): Shader {
        val listColor = mutableListOf<Int>().apply {
            add(bodyColor)
            add(colorTwo)
        }.toIntArray()

        return LinearGradient(
            0f,
            0f,
            centerRingX * 2,
            centerRingY * 2,
            listColor,
            floatArrayOf(0f, 1f),
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT
        )
    }
```

- **Second circle** : Using a tutorial I found (https://medium.com/@yuriyskul/different-ways-to-create-glowing-shapes-in-android-canvas-8b73010411fe), I made a GradialRadient to have a "halo effect"

```
    private fun createRadialGradient(centerRingX: Float, centerRingY: Float): Shader {
        val gradientRadiusPx = ringRadius + glowStrokeWidthPx / 2 + blurRadiusPx

        // transparent
        val innerEndGlowingPx = ringRadius - glowStrokeWidthPx / 2 - blurRadiusPx
        // glowing color
        val innerStartGlowingPx = ringRadius - glowStrokeWidthPx / 4
        // glowing color
        val constantInnerGlowingPx = ringRadius - bodyStrokeWidthPx / 2
        // body color
        val innerBodyEndPx = ringRadius - bodyStrokeWidthPx / 2 - 1
        //body color
        val outerBodyEndPx = ringRadius + bodyStrokeWidthPx / 2 + 1
        // glowing color
        val constantOuterGlowingPx = ringRadius + bodyStrokeWidthPx / 2
        // glowing color
        val outerStartGlowingPx = ringRadius + glowStrokeWidthPx / 4
        // transparent
        val outerEndGlowingPx = ringRadius + glowStrokeWidthPx / 2 + blurRadiusPx

        //  normalized values in same order:
        val innerEndGlowingNormalized = innerEndGlowingPx / gradientRadiusPx
        val innerStartGlowingNormalized = innerStartGlowingPx / gradientRadiusPx
        val constantInnerGlowingNormalized = constantInnerGlowingPx / gradientRadiusPx
        val innerBodyEndNormalized = innerBodyEndPx / gradientRadiusPx
        val outerBodyEndNormalized = outerBodyEndPx / gradientRadiusPx
        val constantOuterGlowingNormalized = constantOuterGlowingPx / gradientRadiusPx
        val outerStartGlowingNormalized = outerStartGlowingPx / gradientRadiusPx
        val outerEndGlowingNormalized = outerEndGlowingPx / gradientRadiusPx

        val stops = floatArrayOf(
            innerEndGlowingNormalized,
            innerStartGlowingNormalized,
            constantInnerGlowingNormalized,
            innerBodyEndNormalized,
            outerBodyEndNormalized,
            constantOuterGlowingNormalized,
            outerStartGlowingNormalized,
            outerEndGlowingNormalized
        )

        val colors = intArrayOf(
            Color.TRANSPARENT,
            glowingColor,
            glowingColor,
            bodyColor,
            bodyColor,
            glowingColor,
            glowingColor,
            Color.TRANSPARENT
        )

        return RadialGradient(
            centerRingX, centerRingY, gradientRadiusPx,
            colors,
            stops,
            Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
        )
    }
```

[image]

- **What I would like to have** : One circle with combinaison of both

  --> A linear gradient to keep the red to blue change on the circle

  --> A radial gradient to keep the halo but with the colors of the circle (so red to blue too)

The goal is to have a fully parametrized custom view (radius of the circle, colors, size ...)

I tried a lot of things but I didn't find anything working.
Don't hesitate if you need more informations.

Thanks for your answers or ideas !